# Datagrid formatting rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid that I am trying to change the individual row colours on using the datagrid_LoadingRow event handler.  The problem I have is, it is colouring every row in the datagrid the same colour instead of each individual row depending on which condition is met.

Here is my code, how do I apply this to each separate row?

```
    private void schDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataRowView dr in schDataGrid.Items)
        {
            string DUEDATE = dr["DUEDATE"].ToString();

            DateTime now = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            DateTime compareDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DUEDATE);
            TimeSpan difference = now - compareDate;

            if (difference.Days <= 0)
            {
                e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.ForestGreen);
                e.Row.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            }
            else if (difference.Days > 0 && difference.Days <= 60)
            {
                e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
                e.Row.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            }
            else if (difference.Days > 60)
            {
                e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                e.Row.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help as always.

Comment: Paint event would be more useful. It's a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function schDataGrid_LoadingRow is called for every single row. 
So instead of looping all your items, take out the item of the row:

```
        var dr = e.Row.Item as yourItem
        // Other stuff....
        if (difference.Days <= 0)
        {
            e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.ForestGreen);
            e.Row.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }
        else if (difference.Days > 0 && difference.Days <= 60)
        {
            e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
            e.Row.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        }
        else if (difference.Days > 60)
        {
            e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            e.Row.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        }
```